# Memory overhead of jit in mono and microsoft .net

Tags: c#, mono, jit

We known jit will generate native code and put them to memory for cache.
Many jit implementation has pretty big memory overhead but few research write about it.
Mono can do a profile and show how many size of jit generated code used.

```
JIT summary
    Compiled methods: 401
    Generated code size: 176811
```

But I didn't have some good example to test about this.
I want to known:
1. Is jit memory overhead large of mono or microsoft .net in normal case? 
2. Will Native code generate many times of  same il code because they are in different thread or appdomain? 
eg: If I create 10000 threads, some native code will repeat 10000 times too?

3. How to reduce the overhead?
eg: aot, disable inlining

Comment: Please ask a single, specific question at a time.

Comment: The size of the generate machine code is never relevant.  Such as the example you gave, it uses 0.008% of the available VM.  Much, much less in a 64-bit process.  Doing *anything* to optimize that is of course a complete waste of your time.  And ours.

Comment: In my research memory overhead of generated machine code in mono is small. But I'm not sure, I want more detail about this. I had a very bad experience of running  service on jit runtime, I wont point thats what language but it waste about 50% ~ 70% memory on machine code store.